# Why aren't I getting input and output from this terminal?

Tags: java, terminal

Here's the code: it successfully opens a terminal but nothing is displayed on the output

```
try {
    String command= "/usr/bin/xterm";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(command);
    BufferedWriter os = 
        new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pr.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader is = 
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";

    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(line);
    }

} catch (Exception io) {    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't write empty catch-blocks. It's just **wrong** and it will cost you many hours of debugging after which you'll feel ... less than perfect.
2. `xterm` produces no output by default. It just displays a window. Try starting `xterm` in a terminal and see which output it produces (in the original terminal, not in the new window!).
3. Read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) and follow **all** of its advice.

Comment: point #1 deserves its own separate upvote.  Every time I find an empty try/catch in production code I have to suppress the urge to go stabby.

Comment: Besides these excellent points, the error stream of the child process needs to be read too

Comment: @Hemal: that's explained in the third item and I don't expect this particular item to be relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4). If you read the whole article you will avoid and understand many pitfalls of the exec command.

Then you can read up on `ProcessBuilder` which is a more modern way to invoke other processes.

Ps. Empty catch block swallow exceptions and make it harder to debug.

Comment: Unfortunately `ProcessBuilder` doesn't solve most of the problems mentioned in this (excellent) article.